# Customize the size and position of background color in webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, css

I have used the following code to format the background color of a webpart but you can still see a little bit sticking out on the sides.

```
<div style="background: #e5e5e5;"> 
 <style>
 </style><img alt="AboutLAI.png"    
 src="/sites/LoanAccountingInitiative/SiteAssets/SitePages/LandingPage/AboutLAI.png" 
 style="margin: 0px;"/>
 <ul>
  <li> 
     <a title="LAI vision, strategic priorities, and objectives" href="/sites/LoanAccountingInitiative/SitePages/Vision.aspx"> 
        <span class="ms-rteFontSize-3">LAI vision</span></a></li>
  <li>
     <span class="ms-rteFontSize-3"></span> 
     <span class="ms-rteFontSize-3"> 
        <a href="/sites/LoanAccountingInitiative/SitePages/Timeline.aspx">LAI timeline</a></span></li>
```

Is there a way to use CSS in the Script Editor to change the styling of the background color?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a bit more HTML so we can try out?

Comment: asuming that you want to change the background of the list items and asuming too, that the items are list (ul -> li)
you can use something like this

    <div id="navlist">
    </div>
    #navlist li:hover {
        background-color:#2EA620;
    }

Comment: @AmalHashim - I have posted more HTML. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @John I think the problem is with this `style="margin: 5px;"`

Comment: @AmalHashim I changed the margin to 0px. That has fixed the padding on the left side but the right side still has some. The code and image reflects those changes. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Set the width of div to the width of img tag